# How to update object property value of an array item in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

```
{
    "_id": "chat",
    "toList": [
        {
            "_id": "person 1",
            "messages": {
                "_id": "1",
                "message": "Message from person 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "Person 2",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "_id": "1",
                    "message": "Message from person 2"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "2",
                    "message": "new message"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hi this is my db customers document. I want to **change(update)** the message property value from **"new message"** to **"new message from person 2"** of **"`messages._id`": "2" of "`toList._id`": "Person 2"**. Please help me to find the proper solution.

My code:

```
db.customers.update({"_id":"Chat", "toList._id":"Person 2", "toList.messages._id":"2"},{$set:{"toList.$.messages.message":"new message from person 2"}}, function(err, res)
{
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: `messages` is an array, so it doesn't have a `message` property itself, its elements do.

Comment: but when i run this code it is adding data to the first element's `messages` of `"_id":"pesron 1"`